# AngularJS Select cleared after Selecting value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a select that is populated via JSON/REST. It populates the dropdown as expected, and gives me the value (an ID) needed when I post the value to my DB, but once I select an option, it clears all the labels in the select so I can't select a different one if I made a mis-click or see the label of what I selected.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="pfcArticlePostCtrl">
<form ng-submit="createTask()">
    <p>
        <select data-ng-model="categoryoptions"
                data-ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in categoryoptions"></select> the value is {{categoryoptions.value}}
    </p>
     <p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="articletitle"
               placeholder="add new task here">
    </p> 
    <p>
        <textarea ng-model="articlesummary"
               placeholder="add summary"></textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="create">
</form>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
// Add new article
pfcControllers.controller('pfcArticlePostCtrl', ['$scope', 'pfcArticles', 'pfcArticleCategories', function ($scope, pfcArticles, pfcArticleCategories) {

var articleentry = new pfcArticles;

$scope.categoryoptions = [];

var articleCategoryNames = pfcArticleCategories.query(function () {

     // Foreach category entry, push values into categoryoptions array
    angular.forEach(articleCategoryNames, function (categoryvalue, categorykey) {

        $scope.categoryoptions.push({
            label: categoryvalue.categoryname,
            value: categoryvalue.categoryid,
        });
    })
});


$scope.createTask = function () {

    articleentry.articletitle = $scope.articletitle;
    articleentry.articlecategoryid = $scope.categoryoptions.value;
    articleentry.articlesummary = $scope.articlesummary;
    articleentry.articlelink = $scope.articletitle.replace(/\s/g, "-").toLowerCase();

    articleentry.$save();
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your `ng-model` and select options @ `opt as opt.label for opt in categoryoptions` are pointing to the same property. So as you select a value from select it sets the ngmodel `categoryoptions` with the selected value(object) and the list of options `categoryoptions` are also the same, So you see that it gets cleared because `categoryoptions` is no longer the select options list. use a different property name for `ng-model` or vice versa.

Example:-

```
<select data-ng-model="selectedCategory"
            data-ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in categoryoptions">   
</select>
```

Or set the value as a property on the array itself,  `categoryoptions.selected` or to enforce dot rule (if you may need) define an object in your controller `$scope.category = {};` and set ng-model as `$scope.category.selected`